# Share to instagram via swift on Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, instagram, xcode7

So in a few other place on stack overflow and online I see this code:

```
func postImage2() {
            var instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")

            if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL!)) {
                var imagePost = image
                var fullPath = documentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("insta.igo")
                var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imagePost).writeToFile(fullPath, atomically: true)
                var rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
                self.docController.UTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
                var igImageHookFile = NSURL(string: "file://\(fullPath)")
                self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: igImageHookFile!)
                self.docController.annotation = ["InstagramCaption":"Text"]
                self.docController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(rect, inView: self.view, animated: true)

            } else {
                print("no instagram found")
            }

        }
```

However, this gives a complaint: stringByAppendingPathComponent is unavailable. UseURLByAppendingPathComponent on NSURL instead. I have heard this is a new initiative that apple is trying to get people to move from string based paths to urls.

In any case, how can I update this code so that it works with URLByAppendingPathComponent?

Comment: Short answer: it isn't possible to upload images to instagram regarding the currently available API

Comment: interesting. source for that?